# OCamllex matching beginning of line?

Tags: ocaml, ocamllex

I am messing around writing a toy programming language in OCaml with ocamllex, and was trying to make the language sensitive to indentation changes, python-style, but am having a problem matching the beginning of a line with ocamllex's regex rules.  I am used to using `^` to match the beginning of a line, but in OCaml that is the string concat operator.  Google searches haven't been turning up much for me unfortunately :( Anyone know how this would work?

Comment: Grammar for the Regular Expressions can be found here; http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual026.html#regexp

Comment: yea i saw that, I was hoping that i was just missing something and that there was more than that. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. It's definitely a natural assumption based on their claim to be similar to Lex and knowledge of general regular expression languages. I'm not sure why they didn't include it; this could be something to ask the fa.caml google group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is explicit support for zero-length matching symbols (like `^` in Perl-style regular expressions, which matches a position rather than a substring). However, you should be able to let your lexer turn newlines into an explicit token, something like this:

**parser.mly**

```
%token EOL
%token <int> EOLWS
% other stuff here
%%
main:
    EOL stmt                { MyStmtDataType(0, $2) }
  | EOLWS stmt              { MyStmtDataType($1 - 1, $2) }
 ;
```

**lexer.mll**

```
{
 open Parser
 exception Eof
}
rule token = parse
    [' ' '\t']           { token lexbuf }     (* skip other blanks *)
  | ['\n'][' ']+ as lxm  { EOLWS(String.length(lxm)) }
  | ['\n']               { EOL }
  (* ... *)
```

This is untested, but the general idea is:

- Treat newlines as staetment 'starters'
- Measure whitespace that immediately follows the newline and pass its length as an `int`

Caveat: you will need to preprocess your input to start with a single `\n` if it doesn't contain one.